# Geometric sum of geometric random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

I am looking to find the probability mass function of $Y=\sum_{i=1}^NX_i$ where $X_i\sim\textrm{Geometric}(a)$ and $N\sim\textrm{Geometric}(b)$. I attempted to do this by finding the probability generating function of $Y$ and comparing it to known probability generating functions to take advantage of the uniqueness property. (In my searches online, it sounds like I should find that $Y\sim\textrm{Geometric}(ab)$.)

(Note that I am using the geometric distribution with support $0,1,\dots$)

I calculated the probability generating function of $X$, $g_X(s)=\frac{a}{1-(1-a)s}$ and correspondingly, $g_N(s)=\frac{b}{1-(1-b)s}$, so the law of total expectation implies that $g_Y(s)=g_N(g_X(s))=\frac{b}{1-(1-b)\frac{a}{1-(1-a)s}}$, however I cannot manipulate this to look like any probability generating function that I recognize, and certainly not $g_Z(s)=\frac{ab}{1-(1-ab)s}$ where $Z\sim\textrm{Geometric}(ab)$. Is there something wrong with my thinking here?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How do you define $Y$ when $N$ equals zero?

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with a more low-tech approach.

Assume that
$$ \mathbb{P}[X_i=k]=p(1-p)^{k-1}, \qquad k=1,2,\ldots \tag{1}$$
and $\mathbb{P}[N=n]=r(1-r)^{n-1}$ for $r=1,2,\ldots$. Then:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \mathbb{P}[Y=m] &=& \sum_{n\geq 1}\mathbb{P}[N=n]\cdot\mathbb{P}[X_1+\ldots+X_n=m]\\&=&\frac{r}{1-r}\sum_{n\geq 1}(1-r)^n\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^n(1-p)^m\cdot r(m,n)\tag{2}\end{eqnarray*} $$
where:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} r(m,n) &=& \#\{(a_1,\ldots,a_n): a_i\in\mathbb{N}_{>0},a_1+\ldots+a_n=m\}\\&=&[x^m]\left(x+x^2+x^3+\ldots\right)^n\\&=&[x^m] \frac{x^n}{(1-x)^n}=\binom{m-1}{n-1}\tag{3}\end{eqnarray*} $$
hence:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \mathbb{P}[Y=m]&=&rp(1-p)^{m-1}\sum_{n\geq 1}\binom{m-1}{n-1}\left(\frac{p-pr}{1-p}\right)^{n-1}\\&=&rp(1-p)^{m-1}\left(1+\frac{p-pr}{1-p}\right)^{m-1}\\&=&pr(1-pr)^{m-1}\tag{4}\end{eqnarray*}$$
proving your claim for geometric distributions supported on $1,2,\ldots$. There is little to change in order to deal with geometric distributions supported on $0,1,\ldots$, too.

Comment: The question does not define what $Y$ is when $N=0$, however I suspect that it is $0$ as that is a requirement to use probability generating functions as that is what it asks for.

Thank you for the low-tech approach, it's definitely good to know that it actually works! However I am required by the question to use probability generating functions to determine $\Pr(Y=n)$. Do you have any idea why the nested probability generating functions approach does not seem to work? It seems to fit all the requirements to make use of the theorem. Namely that $X_i$ are i.i.d. and independent of $N$.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I do feel that an interpretable, 'probabilistic', answer is missing.

Let $X \sim \operatorname{Geometric}(a)$. This can be sampled by tossing a coin with probability $a$ of heads and counting the number of times until a heads comes up; $X$ is this number of times.

Now, upon seeing a head, independently of everything else, *reject* this with probability $1 - b$ (ie, keep with probability $b$). If the head is 'rejected', then you have to keep tossing the coin. Continue like this until you get a head which is 'accepted'. Let $N$ be the number of rejections. Clearly, $N \sim \operatorname{Geometric}(b)$.

Let $Y$ be the final number of tosses. Then, $Y \sim \operatorname{Geometric}(ab)$. You can think of 'rejecting' as turning the coin over, from heads to tails. The probability of an accepted head is $a \cdot b$.

Let $X_i$ be the number of tosses between the $(i-1)$-th and $i$-th head. Then, $X_1, X_2, ... \sim^\mathsf{iid} \operatorname{Geometric}(a)$. The coin tosses are independent of the accept/reject $N$. You keep tossing until an accepted head, so $Y = \sum_{i=1}^N X_i \sim \operatorname{Geometric}(ab)$.